# Throw Custom Exception

Tags: scala, exception

I'm trying to throw a custom exception.

The implementation of the custom exception class is:

```
case class customException(smth:String)  extends Exception
```

In my code I wrapped a piece of code that I'm sure throws throw an exception with try/catch to throw my customException.

```
try{
    val stateCapitals = Map(
      "Alabama" -> "Montgomery",
      "Alaska" -> "Juneau",
      "Wyoming" -> "Cheyenne")

    println("Alabama: " + stateCapitals.get("AlabamaA").get)
}
catch{
    case x:Exception=>throw classOf[CustomException]
}
```

I got a compilation error that says :

```
        found   : java.lang.Class[CustomException]
[INFO]  required:    java.lang.Throwable 
[INFO]       case x:Exception=>throw classOf[CustomException]
```

How could I throw my own custom exception on this case?
Later I'm checking if the thrown exception is of a type[x] to do something specific.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're not throwing an exception, but the class of an exception (just read the compiler error message...). You have to throw an exception instance.

```
case x:Exception => throw new CustomException("whatever")
```

Comment: In the case of case classes, you don't need the `new`.

Comment: That's one of the dumbest questions I have ever asked . The problem that I used to throw "CustomException" as u mentiond b4 I use classOf  but I was getting the same error I mentioned . The thing that pays my attention on ur code is "whatever"..... I forgot to pass the constructor's parameter.   Sorry for being....... "whatever" :)

Comment: @Kim: Indeed. I just wanted to insist on instantiation.

Comment: How can I print the message with the stacktrace?

Answer (score 30):

It would also be helpful to change your Exception class definition as follows:

```
case class customException(smth:String)  extends Exception(smth)
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because by not providing a "message" argument to constructor of the Exception class you effectively invoke the default (no-args) constructor, and this way "lose" the message.  It may be a design choice, where just a Class Name is enough to identify the error, but in most practical cases skipping the Exception(String message) constructor in this case would be an oversight.